# Python: Counting and printing mouse clicks (Zelle's Graphics)

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I am trying to figure out how to count how many times the mouse is clicked in the window in order to set a limit on the amount.

What I am making is a game where a invisible circle must be found and I want the different difficulties to affect how many clicks are allowed until you lose the game. But I am having trouble with the counting of the mouse clicks.

```
    def mouseClicks():
        global click
        click=click+1
```

Not exactly sure how I would set it to check for the win.getMouse every time. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something very simple:

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin("My Window", 100, 100)
    clickCounter = 0
    while clickCounter < 10:
        win.getMouse() # Pause to view result
        clickCounter += 1
        print clickCounter

main()
```

That's not real useful though, as calling `win.getMouse()` pauses until a mouse click.

Zelle is built on top of [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter), but seems to abstract away event driven programming.

However you can still harness the power of Tkinter:

```
from graphics import *

clickCounter = 0

def click(event):
    global clickCounter
    clickCounter += 1
    print clickCounter

def sillytask():
    print 'Just waiting around'
    global clickCounter
    if clickCounter >= 10:
        win.quit()
    else:
        win.after(1000, sillytask)

win = GraphWin("My Window", 100, 100)
win.bind('<Button-1>', click)
win.after(1000, sillytask)
win.mainloop()
```

Here we `bind` the click to a callback function. `sillytask` shows that other things in the main loop can be running and the click event will still fire.